# Running jira at jira.[my domain].com

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, jira

I have jira installed on my server.
It was running at http://[my ip address]:8100. I changed it to http://jira.[my domain].com.

Now after I access it at http://jira.[my domain].com, a browser path changes to http://jira.[my domain].com:8100/secure/Dashboard.jspa.

1. Why does the port show up?
2. Is there any way to remove 8100 port from this redirect. I'd like it to be http://jira.[my domain].com/secure/Dashboard.jspa
3. Also my jira now responds both to jira.[my domain].com and [my ip address]:8100. The latter one is corrupted. Is it possible to stop user accessing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're not mentioning having JIRA configured with SSL which can include needing to place a `proxyName` entry in the `jira/conf/server.xml` which could redirect I'll assume that you haven't gone into the Administration screen and updated your `Base URL` setting. You don't mention what you have listening on port 80 for the jira hostname but I assume it's Apache.

Below is the Apache config I use for my JIRA instance:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jira.example.net

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jira-error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jira-access.log combined

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

    # ProxyRequests Off
    # ProxyPreserveHost on
    # ProxyPass / http://jira.internal.host:8080/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=300
    # ProxyPassReverse / http://jira.internal.host:8080/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName jira.undergrid.net

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jira-error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jira-access.log combined

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/jira.example.net.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/jira.example.net.key
    SSLCACertificatePath  /etc/ssl/certs/

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://jira.internal.host:8080/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=300
    ProxyPassReverse / http://jira.internal.host:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

In my case the Apache and JIRA servers are running on 2 different machines but the config can work regardless of that. With that in place I then updated the `jira/conf/server.xml` to include the following:

```
    <Connector port="8080"

               maxThreads="150"
               minSpareThreads="25"
               maxSpareThreads="75"
               connectionTimeout="20000"

               scheme="https"
               proxyName="jira.example.net"
               proxyPort="443"

               enableLookups="false"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
               redirectPort="8443"
               acceptCount="100"
               disableUploadTimeout="true"/>

        <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
          maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" SSLEnabled="true"
          maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
          enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
          acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
          keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keyAlias="jira.example.net"
          clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"/>

          <Connector port="8009" redirectPort="8443" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

The final step was to update the `Base URL` by logging into JIRA as a JIRA Administrator and going to *Administration* -> *System* -> *General Configuration* and editing the `Base URL` to ready `https://jira.example.net`

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is almost correct.
If you are not able to start 7.3+ Jira server after this, please look into [this link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/JIRA-won-t-start-after-installing-and-configuring-SSL/qaq-p/639260#U682260). There is bug in 7.3+ versions of Jira.

Use this connector:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
              maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" SSLEnabled="true"
              maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25"
              enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
              acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
              clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
              keyAlias="jira" keystoreFile="<JIRA_HOME>/jira.jks" keystorePass="changeit" keystoreType="JKS"/>
```